# How to return one row based upon date in microsoft sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have an internal Department that will be switching account numbers in the future. I am trying to build a stored procedure to return only one of two rows based upon an effective date.

Here's the data makeup

```
|ID | EffectiveDate | AccountNum |
|-- | ------------- | ---------- |
| 1 |  2021-01-01   |   350000   |
| 2 |  2021-09-01   |   950000   |
```

I know this returns all the data

```
SELECT Id, EffectiveDate, AccountNum
        FROM Account
```

This returns only the first row and never the 2nd:

```
 SELECT Id, EffectiveDate, DeptNum
    FROM Account 
    WHERE EffectiveDate <= GETDATE()
```

How would I dynamically return only 1 row based upon today's date?

So if the Effective date is less than today's date get row one. If the Effective Date is equal to or greater than todays date get row two.

Comment: `select top 1 ... order by EffectiveDate desc`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Select only the top 1 deptnum from one of two possible answers given that the EffectiveDate is less than or equal to the current date and use an order by desc too. This ensures that the original EffectiveDate is obtained because the future EffectiveDate has not passed current date. When the future date is equal to or is earlier than the current date then it's value will be returned.

```
select TOP 1 deptnum
from Account
where EffectiveDate <= GETDATE()
order by EffectiveDate desc
```